# Bring Traffic from Specific country on website

Tags: seo

I am SEO expert. I have a problem,problem is I want to bring traffic precisely form Los Angles, America. What is the easy and short cut way?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are some ways you can do

**1- Google AdWords** : AdWords location targeting allows your ads to appear in the geographic locations that you choose: countries, areas within a country, a radius around a location, or location groups. [see here](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722043?hl=en)

**2-Facebook:** Facebook let you to creating Ads like google and you can set it to show your Ads just to people from Los Angles.

OK, and there are a lots of other ways too, and almost all advertising system do it.